# Adding extra choice's to a field in a Django model

Tags: django

If I wanted to to be able to later add extra choice's to my TYPES_CHOICES tuple in the Role class, how would this be achieved? With a form?

```
class Member(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    address = models.ForeignKey(models.ForeignKey(Address)
    memberContactInfo = models.ForeignKey(MemberContactInfo)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)

class Role(models.Model)
    TYPES_CHOICES = (
    ('PLAYER', 'Player'),
    ('CONDUCTOR', 'Conductor'),
    ('COMMITTEEMEMBER', 'Committee Member'),
    ('LIBRARIAN', 'Librarian'),
    ('TUTOR', 'Tutor'),
    ('ACOCOUNTANT', 'Accountant'),
    ('PRESIDENT', 'President'),
    ('CHAIRMAN', 'Chairman'),
    ('SECRETARY', 'Secretary')
    )
    type = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length = 20, choices = TYPES_CHOICES)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028731/how-to-set-choices-in-dynamic-with-django-choicefield. Might help.

Comment: you could add the choice in your models.py and migrate your database using south.