# Django dynamics ChoiceFields choices from APIs raises ValueError

Tags: python, django

I found the answer on this
[How to set choices in dynamic with Django choicefield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028731/how-to-set-choices-in-dynamic-with-django-choicefield)
maersu post has high vote on my question.

The output from `get_branch()` is `["first_branch", "second_branch"]`

`django==1.11`
`python 3.6.0`

`forms.py`

```
class FactoryPOSForm(forms.ModelForm):
    branch_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=['aa', 'bb'])

    class Meta:
        model = FactoryPOS
        fields = [
            'branch_name',
            'dealer_name',
            'shop_name',
            'factory',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['branch_name'].choices = get_branches()
```

**Error:**

```
File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/eneos-factory/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 250, in build_widget_attrs
    if widget.use_required_attribute(self.initial) and self.field.required and self.form.use_required_attribute:
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/eneos-factory/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 690, in use_required_attribute
    return use_required_attribute and first_choice is not None and self._choice_has_empty_value(first_choice)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/eneos-factory/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 673, in _choice_has_empty_value
    value, _ = choice
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
[22/Apr/2017 16:47:04] ERROR [django.server:124] "GET /admin/factories_pos/factorypos/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 445135
```

Where am I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From doc, Choices should be

> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) consisting itself of iterables of exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for this field. If this is given, the default form widget will be a select box with these choices instead of the standard text field

Comment: I am changing my function to follow your answer. I will be back in a moment.

Comment: I was misled `List[str]`. It works then I misinterpret it. Actually have using tuple everytime in the `model` with argument `choices`. But this time it is `Form`. Thank you very much.